# Java | variable value of attribute

Tags: java, jaxb

I need to let a user of my program name an attribute of annotation, so I created fields in that class which could be managed by a user in `main()`, these fields should initialize a `name` attribute in the annotation of a getter, but Intellij IDEA tells that "Attribute value must be constant". Do you have any ideas how to do another way? 
There is the code:

```
public class Model {

    private String a;
    private String b;

    String nameA;

    public User(String a) {
        this.a = a;
    }

    public User(String a, String b) {
        this.a = a;
        this.b = b;
    }

    @XmlElement(name = nameA)
    public String getA() {
        return a;
    }

    public void setA(String a) {
        this.a = a;
    }

}
```

Comment: `@XmlElement(name = "nameA")` and get that field `nameA` by reflection

Comment: It needs to be a constant, so by definition it can't be a variable. So no, you can't do what you want.

Comment: Can you please add a question too? :) I'm afraid, `JaxB` can't handle this. I.e. annotations are getting their values on compile time, while you want to set the value at runtime. I'm aftaid, you'll need either to use DOM to generate the XML, or use some post-processing to rename the tag. The best solution would be to talk to the customer, figuring out why he needs to specify the name - and then solve that problem.

Comment: @TamasRev Not quite correct, so-called "element reference" property can get their element names provided in the runtime.

Answer (score 1):

You can only use [constant expressions](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.28) in annotations.

It appears you want to map your property using a dynamic element name. For this change the type of `JAXBElement<String>` and use the `@XmlElementRef` annotation instead of `@XmlElement`. You can then construct your value as:

```
new JAXBElement(new QName(nameA), String.class, "myValue");
```